# unique_together and implicitly filled-in field in Django admin

Tags: django, admin, unique-constraint, autofill

Say I'm writing a multi-blog application and I want each author to use unique titles for their articles (but unique per user, not globally unique):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #[...]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('title', 'owner'),)
```

Now, I want the author field to be auto-filled by the application:

```
class ArticleAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('owner',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Actually this does not work: if I try to create a new Article with an existing author-title combination, Django will not check the uniqueness (because author is excluded from the form) and I'll get an IntegrityError when it hits the database.

I thought of adding a clean method to the Article class:

```
def clean(self):
    if Article.objects.filter(title=self.title, owner=self.owner).exists():
        raise ValidationError(u"...")
```

But it seems that Article.clean() is called *before* ArticleAdmin.save_model(), so this does not work.

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation) [variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892162/django-1-3-createview-modelform-unique-together-validation-with-one-field-exclu) of this question have been asked already here, but none of the solutions seem to work for me:

- I cannot use Form.clean() or other form methods that don't have the request available, since I need the request.user.
- For the same reason, model-level validation is not possible.
- Some answers refer to class-based views or custom views, but I'd like to remain in the context of Django's Admin.

Any ideas how I can do this without rewriting half of the admin app?

Answer (score 0):

You are finding a way to bring `request` to customized form, in ModelAdmin, actually:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def make_add_form(request, base_form):
    class ArticleForm(base_form):
        def clean(self):
            if Article.objects.filter(title=self.cleaned_data['title'], owner=request.user).exists():
                raise ValidationError(u"...")
            return self.cleaned_data

        def save(self, commit=False):
            self.instance.owner = request.user
            return super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    return ArticleForm


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('owner',)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is None: # add
            kwargs['form'] = make_add_form(request, self.form)
        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```